# AngularJS - NG-Click para repetir bloco de HTML

Tags: angularjs

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário "dinâmico", onde os usuários escolhem  a sequencia, quantidade e quais campos irá preencher.
Então usei ng-click para repetir o código HTML do forme como segue abaixo:

o botões: (São 3 botões, um pra texto, um vídeo, outro pra imagem, copiei apenas um para ficar mais limpo).

```
<div class="col-md-12 bloco_botoes" ng-controller="InformacoesObraController">                
     <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-model="item.texto" ng-click="adicionaTexto()">
         Adicionar<br>TEXTO
     </a>
</div>
```

Meu Controller:

```
function InformacoesObraController($scope) {
     $scope.textos = [];

     $scope.adicionaTexto = function() {
         var elTexto = angular.element(
             '<div class="input-group"><input id="nome_obra" name="texto" class="form-control" type="text-area" required=""></div>'
         );
         angular.element(document.querySelector('#forms-element')).append(elTexto);
     };
};
```

Local onde o bloco HTML é inserido:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <br><br><div id="forms-element"></div>               
  </div>
```

**O Problema:**

Quando vou enviar as informações pro Banco tenho problema pois todos os campos possuem o menos nome (**name="texto"**), então só grava o primeiro bloco.
Estou enviando pra um Banco MongoDB e pensei em converter os dados no POST para JSON, mão não deu certo.

help me please! :)

Comment: @SouzaXavier acredito que você terá que enviar esses dados em uma coleção de "textos".

Comment: @FabioSilvaLima de que forma? Pois já está sendo salvo uma coleção. Mas com penas um Ítem.

Comment: Q pena agora nao consigo te ajudar, amanha eu vejo essa parada

Comment: Pelo que entendi, voce precisa acrescentar um index exemplo: ng-model="item.texto[$index]" Esse index deve ser acrescentado em cada click. Assim no click de acrescentar ele devera percorrer a lista texto.

Comment: Vou tentar implementar este index. Obrigado! @JuniorPorfirio

Answer (score 1):

Cara, você precisa enviar um array de string para o seu backEnd, não sei o que você esta de backEnd, mas acredito que a forma abaixo resolva o seu problema

```
function InformacoesObraController($scope) {

 $scope.countTexto = 0;

 $scope.textos = [];

 $scope.adicionaTexto = function() {
     var elTexto = angular.element(
         '<div class="input-group"><input id="nome_obra" name="texto["' + ($scope.countTexto++) + ']"  class="form-control" type="text-area" required=""></div>'
     );
     angular.element(document.querySelector('#forms-element')).append(elTexto);
  };
};
```

Dessa forma utilizamos o contador countTexto para criar um array de strings